# The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. UPLOADING PDF Buffer to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, pdf-generation, puppeteer, chrome-aws-lambda

I'm trying to upload a PDF generated with chrome-aws-lambda in production and puppeteer in local. It works in local. But send the error of the title in production.

These are the params of presignedS3.

```js
      const pdf = await Helper.getPDFBuffer(html, options);

      const merchantCod = params.merchantId;
      const signedURLExpireSeconds = 60 * 10;
      const rutaDocumento = params.folderMovement + "/"
      const tipoDocumento = "facturaNro"
      const extraRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000 - 1)) + 1;;
      let nroDocumento = params.nro

      const presignedS3UrlPDF = await  s3getSignedUrl("putObject", {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: "another/" + merchantCod + "/" + rutaDocumento + tipoDocumento + nroDocumento + "-" + extraRandomNumber+ ".pdf",
        Expires: signedURLExpireSeconds,
        ContentType: "application/pdf"
      });
      console.log("presignedS3UrlPDF123: ", presignedS3UrlPDF)
      let resultUploadPDF = await uploadPDF(presignedS3UrlPDF, pdf);
```

This is the method**(Where is the error)** to upload the PDF

```js
    static async uploadPDF(presignedS3Url, pdf){
      try {
        let resultado = await axios.put(presignedS3Url,
          Buffer.from(pdf)
        , {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
            }
        });
        console.log("Resultado Subida del PDF", resultado)
        return resultado.statusText;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Mi error 1000", error)
        console.log("El error 123",error.message)
        return error;
      }
    }
```

And this is the method to get PDF Buffer

```js
    static getPDFBuffer = async (html, options) => {
    let browser = null;
    try {
      const executablePath = process.env.IS_OFFLINE
        ? null
        : await chromium.executablePath;
      browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
        args: chromium.args,
        executablePath,
      });

      const page = await browser.newPage();
      const loaded = page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: "load",
      });

      await page.setContent(html);
      await loaded;

      return await page.pdf(options);
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    } finally {
      if (browser !== null) {
        await browser.close();
      }
    }
  };
```